# How can I start a another activity in this Dialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want when I click the 'OK' button I get to the 'PickSeatActivity'.
This is what I tried, but android studio underlines 'Intent' Object with a red line

```
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this.requireActivity())

         // Dialog will have "Make a selection" as the title
         builder.setMessage("Details successfully captured.Do you wish to proceed and book your seat?")
             .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
                 val intent = Intent(PickSeatActivity::class.java)
                 startActivity(intent)


             }
             // A "Cancel" button that does nothing
             .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id ->
                 // Nothing happening here either
             }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Replace your code**

```
val intent = Intent(PickSeatActivity::class.java)
             startActivity(intent)
```

**TO**

```
val intent = Intent(this.requireActivity(), PickSeatActivity::class.java)
             startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: thanks, I was able to start the activity after I replaced the code.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this

```
val intent = Intent(this@yourActivity, PickSeatActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

or

```
val intent = Intent(this.requireActivity(), PickSeatActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 1):

`packageContext` is required:  `public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`

```
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this.requireActivity())

     // Dialog will have "Make a selection" as the title
     builder.setMessage("Details successfully captured.Do you wish to proceed and book your seat?")
         .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
             val intent = Intent(this.requireActivity(),PickSeatActivity::class.java)
             startActivity(intent)


         }
         // A "Cancel" button that does nothing
         .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id ->
             // Nothing happening here either
         }
```